# jQuery event, WHILE select is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the DOM is loaded completely, I have two select fields on the page.

When the value of the first one is changed, the values of the second one will be generated and meanwhile, it (the second select field) gets disabled (until the data is fully loaded) and once completed, it will be enabled.

I want to disable a button WHILE the select field is disabled.

I tried the following but cant get it to work properly

```
if ($('#mySelect').is(':disabled')) {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
} else if ($('#mySelect').is(':enabled'))
{
 $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

So basically it constantly needs to be listening to the select disable or enable event.

Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you put this snippet of code in the same place where you disable the second select? You don't even need the if condition. Please post the code where you disable your second select

Comment: Probably not your issue, but you could shorten your logic a bit...  $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', $('#mySelect').is(':disabled'));

Comment: How do you load the 2nd `<select>` values? I assume `jQuery.ajax()` or one of it's shortcut functions, in which case you can handle disabling / enabling the button there.

Comment: Can describe _"cant get it to work properly"_ ?

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of hard to help with so many details missing from your issue, but may be you can try this:

HTML

```
<select id="mySelect1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="mySelect2" disabled>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled/>
```

jQuery

```
$('#mySelect1').on('change', function () {
$('input[type="submit"], #mySelect2').attr('disabled', false);

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6yvug1m/)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

to check if element disabled or not

```
if($('element').attr('disabled') == 'undefind'){
    alert('enabled');
}else{
    alert('disabled');
}
```

to make element disabled

```
$('element').prop('disabled',true);
```

to make element enabled

```
$('element').prop('disabled',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button id="mySelect">ButtonA</button>
<input type="submit">ButtonB</input>
```

Jquery

```
//Defining the jquery object for cache purpose in the future
var $obj1 = $("#mySelect");
var $obj2 = $("input[type='submit']");
//if the button is disabling.
if($obj1.prop("disabled")){
   $obj1.prop("disabled",true);
   $obj2.prop("disabled",$obj1.prop("disabled"));
}
```